# Weird behavior when scaling object

Tags: three.js

I have an object that is loaded via ObjectLoader. I am trying to clone the object, replace it's material, and scale it in place to use as a selection indicator when the original object is selected via raycasting. The below code blow shows how I am cloning the object, replacing material, and scaling.

```
let selectionIndicatorMesh = mesh.clone();
selectionIndicatorMesh.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
selectionIndicatorMesh.material.transparent = true;
selectionIndicatorMesh.material.opacity = 0.4;
selectionIndicatorMesh.scale.x = selectionGlowMesh.scale.x * 1.15;
selectionIndicatorMesh.scale.y = selectionGlowMesh.scale.y * 1.15;
selectionIndicatorMesh.scale.z = selectionGlowMesh.scale.z * 1.15;
scene.add( selectionIndicatorMesh );
```

When I increase the scale of x, or y, the object scales from the center out and gets wider and the DEPTH increases, oddly enough... The REALLY odd part is when I scale the z value the object not only increases in height, but moves up the Y-axis a seemingly arbitrary distance. The `mesh.up` is `{ x: 0, y: 1, z: 0 }`.

Though I'm completely baffled at this point, I'm new to 3D environments, so I'm sure this has a simple explanation that I for some reason cannot find. I have tried changing the origin point before scaling with `mesh.geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation( 0, 0, -( delta / 2 ) )` without success. This moves the object back down the Y-axis, but the original object is not fully encompassed within the new object.

Note: `selectionIndicatorMesh` has no group, and the scene is it's parent.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone encountering this, here is how I solved it.

```
let selectionIndicatorMesh = mesh.clone();
selectionIndicatorMesh.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
selectionIndicatorMesh.material.transparent = true;
selectionIndicatorMesh.material.opacity = 0.4;

let box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( selectionIndicatorMesh );
let offset = box.getCenter();

selectionIndicatorMesh.geometry.center();

selectionIndicatorMesh.position.set( offset.x, offset.y, offset.z );

selectionIndicatorMesh.scale.x = selectionGlowMesh.scale.x * 1.15;
selectionIndicatorMesh.scale.y = selectionGlowMesh.scale.y * 1.15;
selectionIndicatorMesh.scale.z = selectionGlowMesh.scale.z * 1.15;
scene.add( selectionIndicatorMesh );
```

1. Create a `Box3` from your mesh: `let box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( selectionIndicatorMesh );`
2. Save a reference to it's offsets: `let offset = box.getCenter();`
3. Center your mesh `selectionIndicatorMesh.geometry.center();`
4. Set the position of your mesh to the saved offsets `selectionIndicatorMesh.position.set( offset.x, offset.y, offset.z );`